# How to check if an Activity receives an intent sent from another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

I send an intent from activity1 to activity2, after clicking on a button.
I send extras with this intent.

Using espresso, I need to test whether the activity2 received this intent, sent from activity1.

I have no idea, how to do it. I have not written any code.

Comment: Check if `getIntent()` is null in the second Activity is the common approach

Comment: I need to write tests, using "espresso" framework. This won't work.

Comment: Last time I checked, you can write  a null check in a unit test. Espresso is just java

Comment: This works when I am writing code in my activities, but not for testing.
For this I need to use espresso intents, but I don't know how.

Comment: It seems that, there's no way I can do, what I wanted to do. At least not yet.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say from ActivityA you click a button which starts ActivityB:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
                intent.putExtra("MY_EXTRA", "MY EXTRA VALUE");
```

A test which checks that you're sending the right data to ActivityB would be:

```
@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<ActivityA> intentsTestRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(ActivityA.class);

@Test
public void testIntents() {
    //from ActivityA, click the button which starts the ActivityB
    onView(withText("ClickMe")).perform(click());

    //validate intent and check its data
    intended(allOf(
            toPackage("com.your.package.name"),
            hasExtra("MY_EXTRA", "MY EXTRA VALUE")
    ));
}
```

Check out the examples provided by google: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample

and some documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents.html.

Answer (score -2):

first use `getIntent()`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

then using intent object to receive data from another activity

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("your key");
```

Comment: This would be the case if I was working with activities. But I want to test those activities. i.e unit testing.